# App theme showing on preview but not on phone

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, themes

I have this calculator app in android studio that works perfectly fine, but I selected a theme that is `Material.Voice`and it shows on the preview. But when I run, the app goes right back to regular theme. How do I fix this? Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is my styles file:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Here is my layout acticty main file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="number1"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="number2"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/switch2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fed136"
                android:text="Radians"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radians"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch3" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/switch3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Degree"
                android:background="#fed136" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Degrees"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch3" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sum"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="-"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="x"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="/"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="SQ"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="SR"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="C"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="E"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="%"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="sin"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button19"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="cos"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="tan"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cube"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#fed136"
    android:text="CU"
    tools:text="CU" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textSize="33sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="5"
        android:stepSize="5"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my activity main land file(when you turn the phone sideways):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="number1"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="number2"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/switch2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fed136"
                android:text="Radians"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radians"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch3" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/switch3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Degree"
                android:background="#fed136" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Degrees"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch3" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="x" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="/" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="SQ" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="SR" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="C" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="E" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="%" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="sin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button19"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="cos" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fed136"
        android:text="tan" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cube"
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#fed136"
    android:text="CU"
    tools:text="CU" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sum"
    android:layout_width="444dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp">

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="33sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="5"
        android:stepSize="5"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Oh, and just in case you need it, here is my java file:

```
package com.example.lenovouser.calculatoraghav;
//IMPORT
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// ASSIGNING THE NAMES OR VARIABLES
TextView result, textView8;
EditText number1, number2;
Button add,subtract,divide,multiply,squareroot,square,cube,clear,Exponent,percent,sin 
d, cosd, tand;
ToggleButton switch2, switch3;
double resultnum;
int num1,num2,num3;
boolean radient, degree;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //ASSIGNING THE VARIABLES TO THE ANDROID WIDGETS.
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sum);
    number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1);
    number2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2);
    add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    subtract = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    multiply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    divide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    squareroot =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    square = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Exponent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
    percent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
    sind = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button18);
    cosd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button19);
    tand = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button20)        ;
    switch2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
    switch3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.switch3);
    textView8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    cube = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cube);



    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

@Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //ADD
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText() .toString());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText() .toString());
        resultnum = num1 + num2;
        result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
}
});




    subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        //SUBTRACT
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText() .toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText() .toString());
            resultnum = num1 - num2;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
        }
    });




    multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        //MULTIPLY
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText() .toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText() .toString());
            resultnum = num1 * num2;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
        }
    });





    divide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        //DIVIDE
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText() .toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText() .toString());
            resultnum = num1 / num2;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
        }
    });


    squareroot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        //SQUAREROOT
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText() .toString());

            resultnum = (Math.sqrt(num1));
            result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
        }
    });


    square.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        //SQUARE
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText() .toString());

            resultnum = num1*num1;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
        }
    });


    cube.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        //SQUARE
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText() .toString());

            resultnum = num1*num1*num1;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
        }
    });


    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
        //CLEAR
            num1 = (0);
            num2 = (0);
            num3 = (0);
            number1.setText("");
            number2.setText("");
            //txt.setText("");
            resultnum = 0;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
        }
    });


    Exponent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            //EXPONENT
            int p = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText() .toString());
            int e = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText() .toString());
            resultnum = (Math.pow((double)p, (double)e));
            result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
        }
    });



    percent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            //PERCENT
            Double percentage = 
Double.valueOf(number1.getText().toString());
            Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
            Double resultnum = percentage * num2 / 100;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
        }
    });




    sind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            //SIN num2

            if (degree)
            {
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
                //num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
                resultnum = Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(num1));
                result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
            }

            if (radient){
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
                //num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
                resultnum = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(num1));
                result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));

                if (!degree)
                {

                }

                if (!radient){

                }
            }
        }
    });


    cosd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //COS num2
            if (degree)
            {
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
               // num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
                resultnum = Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(num1));
                result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
            }

           if (radient){
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
                //num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
                resultnum = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(num1));
                result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));

            }


            if (!degree)
            {

            }

            if (!radient){

            }
        }

    });


    tand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            //TAN num2

            if (degree)
            {
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
               //num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
                resultnum = Math.tan(Math.toDegrees(num1));
                result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
            }

            if (radient){
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
               // num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
                resultnum = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(num1));
                result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));

            }



            if (!degree)
            {

            }

            if (!radient){

            }
        }
    });


    switch2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            //switchR
            radient = true;
            degree = false;

            textView8.setText(("Radians MODE"));
        }
    });

    switch3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            //switchD
            degree = true;
            radient = false;
            textView8.setText(("Degree MODE"));
        }
    });


}}
```

Comment: add theme in style.xml, selecting theme in preview editor will not have any impact on actual screen layout

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: in your style.xml change your parent theme to your desired theme.

Comment: I want to change it to material.voice, but I dont know how

Comment: i am not sure about material.voice , but if you want to change your theme from light to dark you can change your parent theme to any dark one or set theme for any particular activity.. please refer this link for better understanding https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes